# How to pass php variables from views to route UI automatically in laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel-5

Below instead of [4], I need to represent a php variable($title). How should be change? Please help me soon.

```
<a href="{{ route('welcome_index', [4]) }}">test</a>
```

Comment: what??? are you sure!! you are questioning!!

Comment: Yeah. Above top is my question

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read for you convenient http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

You would simple put the variable in the call. It should work:

```
<a href="{{ route('welcome_index', $title) }}">test</a>
```